# Xamarin Form Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) Not working. Failing to load a style file

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) in Xamarin Form. I have added the Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) file in PCL project and i'm trying to call CSS it's not loading giving the exception. Even i have given the full permission and following the same step from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/)

Already I have set the Build Action for this css file - **EmbeddedResource**

----Code-----

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}

.frameStyle {
    background-color: rgb(50,50,255);
}
```

Using XAML.

```
      <ContentPage.Resources>
        <StyleSheet Source="Assets/styles.css" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

I'm getting the exception to load CSS file as below.

```
Resource: 'Views/DashBoard/Assets/styles.css' not found.
Stack Exception:
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.CreateValuesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x0024e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\CreateValuesVisitor.cs:94 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x000ac] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:149 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00044] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:143 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00079] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:202 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode rootnode, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydrationContext visitorContext) [0x00054] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:140 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.String xaml) [0x00058] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:89 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType) [0x00026] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:67 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000]
```

Please suggest me what mistake i'm doing thanks.

Comment: do you get this error in android or ios?

Comment: this is coming in IOS

Comment: Do you have the css in your android assets folder then?

Comment: I don't have any CSS file in android assets . i'm using the from PCL only

Comment: I'm facing issues in IOS not in android

Comment: Put forword slash (/) before Assests
like <StyleSheet Source="/Assets/styles.css" />

Answer (score 1):

Related to your link: *"The StyleSheet.Source property specifies the style sheet as a URI relative to the location of the enclosing XAML file, or relative to the project root if the URI starts with a /"*

=> I think you missed "/" charater. it should be:

```
<StyleSheet Source="/Assets/styles.css" />
```

Comment: If i'm using this  <ContentPage.Resources>
                <StyleSheet Source="/Assets/styles.css" />
              </ContentPage.Resources> now exception is different- Position 11:18. Source only accepts Relative URIs

Answer (score 1):

For style sheet references I found that when I moved my .xaml files to a Views folder I had to alter the path to the css to use ".." notation, e.g.:

```
<StyleSheet Source="../../Styles.css" />
```

If I use a "/" to signify the project root I receive the error:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 14:10. Source only
>   accepts Relative URIs occurred

Tested using Xamarin forms 3.2 .Net Standard 2 using Android and iOS

Answer (score 0):

Still I'm getting same issues . Everything working path is correct all CSS effect are working fine but still Getting path issues.

---

if you getting issues you can use  inline style or use resource dictionary

Comment: This answer isn't very clear. Can you provide more detail?